# White and Chrome ball in material preview mode

Tags: 3d-view

[image: p]

I'm using Blender 2.9.
How do I display white/chrome balls in Material preview mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be sure to have the HDRI Preview checkbox checked in the Viewport Overlays menu.

[image]